# JSON array into HTML table

Tags: html, arrays, json

Looking for a solution to achieve an HTML table that takes the "title" from the JSON file and puts it in the first column of a 2 column table and the second column has the "description".

The description has to be tier as bullet points as it is an array within an array in the JSON file. The current way it is working is that it is one big block of data in the second column which looks like a giant sentence. I've tried putting each bullet point into its separate key pair but it is not feasible as it is time-consuming. Is there an option for an if statement that iterates over the array within an array? Open for other script alternatives.

```js
var data = [
 {
  "title": "title1",
  "description":["description1","description2"]
 },
 {
  "title": "title2",
  "description":["description3","description4"]
 }
]

$(document).ready(function(){
    var list = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      list += '<tr>';
      list += '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
      list += '<td>'+value.description+'</td>'
      list += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#table1').append(list);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current method is fine. You just need to add an `$.each` inside an `$.each`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("data.json", function (data) {
        var list = '';
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            list += '<tr><td>' +
                value.title +
                '</td><td><ul>';
            $.each(value.description, function (key, value) {
                list += "<li>" + value + "</li>";
            })
            list += '</ul></td></tr>';
        });
        $('#table1').append(list);
    });
});
```

```js
var data = [{
    "title": "title1",
    "description": ["description1", "description2"]
  },
  {
    "title": "title2",
    "description": ["description3", "description4"]
  }
]

$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = '';
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    list += '<tr><td>' +
      value.title +
      '</td><td><ul>';
    $.each(value.description, function(key, value) {
      list += "<li>" + value + "</li>";
    })
    list += '</ul></td></tr>';
  });
  $('#table1').append(list);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT: Improved Version:**
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Examath/6b71ku4r/21/)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. How would I add secondary bullet points within the primary bullet points? So I could have a bullet point named test1 and then within test1 there is 2 bullet points named test2 and test3.

Comment: To reword my phrasing, I am looking to create a multi-level bullet system but only by 1 more level. I've been trying multiple methods but I can't seem to figure out how to format the JSON or the script.

Comment: All you need are **arrays** inside the array inside the array, then use an `if/else` to detect whether the bullet point is a single string or an array, and if true, use another `$.each` to place the seconsary bullet points

Comment: Do you have any websites I can look at to assist me in nesting this many arrays in JSON?

Comment: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) is a great website to start with (eg: [Lists](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp), [arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp), [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp) etc), but being able to combine those different skills is the most important. Most of this is really my own experience. Anyway, I've fixed the above answer's bug and created a fiddle with secondary bullet points. [JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Examath/6b71ku4r/21/)